# Iceberg tables with hive thrift server problem - why DDL commands performs asynchronously

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake, pyhive, apache-iceberg, spark-thriftserver

I am using sqlalchemy with [pyhive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive) connector to execute SQL statements on Spark cluster, which running [hive thrift server](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/hiveserver).

Most things are straightforward with native spark and delta tables. I.g. I can drop and create tables like

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('hive://hive-thriftserver-host:10000/default', echo=True)

engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS baz")
engine.execute("CREATE TABLE baz (id int not null) USING DELTA")
engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS baz")
engine.execute("CREATE TABLE baz (id int not null) USING DELTA")
```

So everything is ok and behave like expected.

But with [Iceberg](https://iceberg.apache.org/) tables things become complicated. It looks like DDL commands are just scheduled for execution, so performed asynchronously in background even in transaction, so after `drop table` it removed from the catalog instantly, but some processes prevents from creation of same table during some period of time (~30 seconds).

```
engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bear PURGE")
engine.execute("CREATE TABLE bear (id int not null) USING ICEBERG")
engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bear PURGE")
engine.execute("CREATE TABLE bear (id int not null) USING ICEBERG")
```

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyhive.exc.OperationalError) TExecuteStatementResp(...
[TABLE_OR_VIEW_ALREADY_EXISTS] Cannot create table or view `default`.`bear` because it already exists.
Choose a different name, drop or replace the existing object, or add the IF NOT EXISTS clause to tolerate pre-existing objects.'))
[SQL: CREATE TABLE bear (id int not null) USING ICEBERG]
```

After a while I can create this table sucessfuly.

Could anyone please give ideas how to manage this and deal with such behavior? Again - checking existence of table with `SHOW TABLES IN default` does not working, because tables drops from catalog instantly. I searched for config options for table creation, but find nothing about sync/async behavior.

Also there is an issue, even after `DROP TABLE` that I can not create table with same name using spark or delta, it looks like even after `DROP TABLE bear PURGE` table content remains in storage and prevents from creation other table types.

```
engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bear PURGE")
engine.execute("CREATE TABLE bear (id int not null)")
```

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyhive.exc.OperationalError) TExecuteStatementResp(...
 [LOCATION_ALREADY_EXISTS] Cannot name the managed table as `spark_catalog`.`default`.`bear`, as its associated location 's3a://s3host/user/hive/warehouse/bear' already exists. 
Please pick a different table name, or remove the existing location first."), operationHandle=None)
[SQL: CREATE TABLE bear (id int not null)]
```

So it double strangeness of such async DDL behavior.